# Databricks Community Edition conflicting Scala libraries or JARs attached to the cluster

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

Everytime I attempted to execute any Scala code on Databricks Community Edition, I get the following error message:

`java.lang.Exception: An error occurred while initializing the REPL. Please check whether there are conflicting Scala libraries or JARs attached to the cluster, such as Scala 2.11 libraries attached to Scala 2.10 cluster (or vice-versa)`.

Can someone let me know how to resolve this?

Comment: ok, I changed the Databricks Runtime version on the cluster to 7.0 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.0, Scala 2.12). When I now run any scala code I now get the error: 
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Error accessing /databricks/jars/adal4j-1.6.0.jar. I installed adal4j-1.6.0.jar in the location /databricks/jars, but I'm still getting the same error. Any thoughts?

Comment: do you see this library in the Cluster properties? Also, it's recommended to use MSAL4J instead of ADAL4J

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly add library, for example via Maven coordinates (this could be preferable, as it will pull all dependencies as well), or from the DBFS or S3, so the runtime can distribute this library to all nodes in the cluster.  For example, I'm adding [MSAL](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-java) instead of ADAL:

[image: Adding MSAL library]

and after it's installed, I can access to it without any issue (I've used Runtime 6.5):

[image: Using the MSAL library]

Comment: Morning Alex, thanks for reaching out. Going to try your suggestion now.

Comment: Alex, I tried your suggestion with the following Runtime 6.5 (includes Apache Spark 2.4.5, Scala 2.11), but I got the error 'java.lang.Exception: An error occurred while initializing the REPL. Please check whether there are conflicting Scala libraries or JARs attached to the cluster, such as Scala 2.11 libraries attached to Scala 2.10 cluster (or vice-versa).' Going to try again with Runtime 7.0

Comment: Alex, I'm unfortunately still getting the same error with Runtime 7.0: 
scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Error accessing /databricks/jars/adal4j-1.6.0.jar. I'm not sure how to include images in StackOverflow, but you can take my word that I installed com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:1.6.1
Any other thoughts?

Comment: do you have any other libraries added? For me it just worked out of box on the community edition

Comment: Hi Alex, I don't have any libraries added as you showed me in your screenshot, but I do have libraries in the following folder /FileStore/jars/maven .. I read somewhere that I need to delete those libraries, but I'm not sure how to delete them. What do you think?

Comment: you can delete them using `%fs rm path...`

Comment: So, Alex, I have removed all the JARs and installed com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:1.6.1, but I'm now once again getting the error ```scala.reflect.internal.FatalError: Error accessing /databricks/jars/adal4j-1.6.0.jar``` You help very much appreciated.

Comment: sorry, I'm out of ideas... if you're using `msal4j`, then it's not clear from where the error about `adal4j` is coming. Have you restarted the cluster?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the cluster multiple times, maybe someone else from SE will step in - I should point out that I'm using the Community Edition

Comment: Yes I have restarted the cluster multiple times. Thanks for your help anyway, maybe someone else from SE will step in - I should point out that I'm using the Community Edition

Comment: Very strange. What version of the community edition are you using?